Gradle Build failing due to UnsupportedClassVersionError. How can I solve this?
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: androidx/lifecycle/lint/LifecycleRuntimeIssueRegistry has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
Getting this error while building signed apk but I can able to build unsigned apk without any error.
I tried to change sdk 33 to 32 but still getting same issue also I tried to use different gradle version but still same no results.

You need to upgrade jdk to version 11 at least.
